# Recover a Cardano wallet offline

Tags: wallet, javascript, seed-phrase

Is there a way to recover or generate the addresses of my wallet (24 seed) without using external servers (JavaScript)? Just like we do with other blockchains?
Example: https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

Answer (score 1):

My preference is to use a javascript library for this.

For example, use https://github.com/StricaHQ/bip32ed25519 to generate/convert the seed phrase to a private/public key.

Then use a javascript/typescript Tx builder library like Helios https://github.com/Hyperion-BT/helios to extract an address from a public key.  No servers involved.

Comment: Do you have a working example combining both libraries?

Comment: Yes.  Here is a working example using both libraries to do a multi-signature nft with a front-end browser wallet and an back-end private key.   https://github.com/lley154/helios-examples/blob/main/nft-multisig/pages/api/getSignature.ts

Answer (score 1):

@enzo to generate offline addresses from mnemonic, you can use cardano-addresses https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses

Comment: Can´t see a working example in JavaScript where I pass a mnemonic and I generate addresses with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using cardano-cli and cardano-address (or cardano-wallet instead of cardano-address, with the same parameters) using the script here:
https://gist.github.com/cardano-apexpool/99784308812bdf7aa01446fa95f47fd2
I've been using it a lot in the last year.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I used the Mnemonic Method detailed here:

https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-ada/guide-how-to-build-a-haskell-stakepool-node/part-iii-operation/setting-up-payment-and-stake-keys

You'll need cardano-wallet on an air-gapped machine.